# Повесила на кнопки listener, а он срабатывает только на одну

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

[image]

У меня есть таблица, в ней циклом выводится информация. Для каждого юзера создается кнопка, но срабатывает только первая. Дальше в консоли просто нет события. Названия класса одинаковое. Событие весит на именно на классе. С чем может быть связано?

Comment: Потому что вы вешаете событие не циклом наверняка

Comment: let delbtn = document.querySelector('.edit_btn');
delbtn.addEventListener('click', function(){}

Классы есть на кнопках, когда выводятся из цикла, отдельным файлом я обращаюсь к ним

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать))

Comment: У меня не получится прикрутить в цикл, я вывожу через php (((

Comment: @Anches Тогда - все, выключайте компьютер.

Comment: @Anches селектор `.querySelector` - находит первое совпадение, чтоб найти все элементы с таким классом необходимо использовать или `getElementsByClassName` или `.querySelectorAll`
Дальше можно через foreach присвоить событие для всех элементов

Comment: Спасибо большое всем за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.edit_btn').forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', function(e { ... }));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]